# Function changes const object

Tags: c++, constants

I have function which accepts const reference as argument. It should not change argument, but it does (variable "_isVertex"). How can this be fixed? Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Element
{
public:
    bool isVertex() const
    { return _isVertex; };

private:
    bool _isVertex = true;
};

class ElementContainer : public vector <Element>
{
public:
    void push(const Element &t)
    {
        // here everything is fine
        cerr << t.isVertex() << ' ';
        push_back(t);
        // and here _isVertex is false, should be true!
        cerr << t.isVertex() << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    ElementContainer vertex;

    vertex.push({});
    vertex.push(vertex[0]);
}
```

Comment: Plus one: you've got me. Note that the C++ standard library containers are not designed to be base classes.

Comment: `const` at the end of the function declaration only guarantees that the state of the class won't change as a result of calling the function.  The value returned is not const, and can be changed after the fact.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Consider carefully `vertex.push(vertex[0]);`. `t` in the function `push` is a constant reference to `vertex[0]`.

But after the `push_back`, the contents of the vector have moved (due to a memory reallocation), and therefore `vector[0]` has moved elsewhere. `t` is now a *dangling reference*.

That's *undefined behaviour*. **Boom**.

Comment: Worth noting that apparently `t` is pushed into the newly allocated backing store _after_ the existing data is copied over and the old backing store is deallocated.